# Subform not loading any records where RecordSource is set via VBA (and other errors)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a search tool that has a few issues I can't seem to iron-out. On the main form is a selection of text boxes for the user to enter search filters against and then a command button for them to execute the search and another command button for them to empty/reset the search text boxes.

Below the text boxes is a subform (set to continuous form), which displays the search results.

On the main form is this public function which builds up the `WHERE` clause for an SQL statement that will be used to update the subform's RecordSource (i.e. pass what was entered in the text boxes on the main form to the `WHERE` clause for the subform's search results.:

```vb
Public Function BuildFilter() As Variant

    Dim varWhere As Variant
    Dim tmp As String

        tmp = """"

        varWhere = Null

        If Me.txtProspCode > "" Then

         varWhere = varWhere & "[ProspectusCode] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.txtProspCode & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.cboDeliveryOrg > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[DeliveryOrganisation] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.cboDeliveryOrg & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.cboLCdept > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[LcDepartment] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.cboLCdept & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.txtCollTitle > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[ColloquialCourseTitle] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.txtCollTitle & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.txtAimTitle > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[LarsAimTitle] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.txtAimTitle & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.txtAimRef > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[LarsAimRef] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.txtAimRef & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.cboCourseLevel > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[CourseLevel] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.cboCourseLevel & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.cboCourseType > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[CourseType] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.cboCourseType & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If Me.cboAcYear > "" Then

            varWhere = varWhere & "[Academic Year] like " & tmp & "*" & Me.cboAcYear & "*" & tmp & " And "

        End If

        If IsNull(varWhere) Then

            varWhere = ""

        Else

            varWhere = "WHERE " & varWhere

            If Right(varWhere, 5) = " And " Then

                varWhere = Left(varWhere, Len(varWhere) - 5)

            End If

        End If

    BuildFilter = varWhere

End Function
```

Also on the main form is the following code for when the user clicks the "search" button. It simply takes what was built for the `WHERE` clause in the above function and adds it to the appropriate place on the subform's `RecordSource` SQL statement:

```vb
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Me.SearchSubForm.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblProspectus " & BuildFilter
    Me.SearchSubForm.Requery

End Sub
```

And finally, also on the main form is the following code for when the user clicks the "clear search filters" button. It simply sets all search text boxes to 0-length strings and then sets the subform's record source to an empty row of results:

```vb
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

    Dim NoRecords As String

    NoRecords = "SELECT " _
              & "'' As ProspectusCode, " _
              & "'' As DeliveryOrganisation, " _
              & "'' As LcDepartment, " _
              & "'' As LarsAimRef, " _
              & "'' As LarsAimTitle, " _
              & "'' As ColloquialCourseTitle, " _
              & "'' As CourseLevel, " _
              & "'' As CourseType, " _
              & "'' As [Academic Year]"

    Me.SearchSubForm.Form.RecordSource = NoRecords

    Me.SearchSubForm.Requery

End Sub
```

Problems I'm having:

1. The "search" command is not returning any records when I try a search I know should return results in the subform. I've used `Debug.Print Me.SearchSubForm.Form.RecordSource` to see what was getting passed to the RecordSource and the SQL seemed fine to me... I even copy-pasted it in to the subform's Record Source manually in Design View and the form opened with the search results I was expecting... weird.
2. The "clear search filters" command works as long as I don't click the "search" command beforehand, otherwise it errors stating that the record source doesn't exist, quoting the SQL I passed in to the `RecordSource` for the "clear search filters" `OnClick` vba... again, weird. Almost as if the "Search" command's failure to produce records is causing an issue with any other attempt to change the subform's Record Source.
3. This subform, related command buttons and vba is working fine on a different main form! I'm pretty sure I've changed all references to this other main form I'm using...

**Update:**
I've found a workaround... I changed the table used in the SQL from a Table to a Query and now it seems to work fine... Don't know why though so would still appreciate any explanation.

Comment: I usually set the RecordSource in design view and just use filters after that. There's not much advantage to resetting the RecordSource every time, although I'm not sure if there's much disadvantage either. On the technical side, the both require a trip to the server/database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the main form needs to refresh the subform in order to see the changes, and to do this you need "bangs" and not "dots".  Try adding a Forms![MainFormName]![SubformName].Form.Requery and see if that works.